# Dynamically add elements each time with new scope in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Each time I append an li to my ul i want new id like new_id_(index_number) i.e( id_1, id_2 so on. ). I am using a template to which contains **li** to be appended , the reason i am using a template because it contains a lot of data like 3-4 forms which has too-many fields. I am using the following code : 
***My Code Snippet:***

```
<div ng-controller="ContractsController">
 <ul id="contracts">
   <li id="new_{{indx}}"></li>
 </ul>
<button class="add_new" add-contracts>Add New Item</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var app = angular.module('AjApp', []);

 app.controller('ContractsController', function ( $scope ) {
    $scope.indx = 1;
 });

 app.directive('addContracts', function ( $templateRequest, $templateCache, $compile ) {       
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, ele, attr) {

            ele.on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $contracts = jQuery("ul#contracts");
                ++scope.indx;

               $templateRequest("add_contracts.html" ).then(function(html){
                  var template = angular.element(html);
                  $contracts.append(template);
                  $compile(template)(scope);
               });


            });
        },
    };
});


</script>
```

The code is appending the **li** to the **ul** but each time I click on ***Add New Item button*** all of the **li's** updated to same **id** . 
What is the problem ? Am I missing something ? Please suggest me a way to solve the problem. Any help will really appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new child scope for each contract, and each child scope contains its own id.

Also, The logic handled by the add-contracts directive could probably be handled by the controller. That way you don't have to select the div using `jQuery("ul#contracts")`. In my example I changed it to use a css class, and the selector becomes `$element.find('.contracts')`.

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rs1whmo7/

Comment: It's perfectly what i want. Thank a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `++scope.$parent.indx` instead of `++scope.indx`

Comment: Not a luck, same result. all of the id's of li updating to new id

Comment: Can you please share add_contracts.html file?

Answer (score 0):

USe scope false instead of true

app.directive('addContracts', function ( $templateRequest, $templateCache, $compile ) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, ele, attr) {

```
        ele.on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $contracts = jQuery("ul#contracts");
            ++scope.indx;

           $templateRequest("add_contracts.html" ).then(function(html){
              var template = angular.element(html);
              $contracts.append(template);
              $compile(template)(scope);
           });


        });
    },
};
```

});

> > OR If you still want to inherit from parent scope keep the index in an object

```
div ng-controller="ContractsController">
 <ul id="contracts">
   <li id="new_{{count.indx}}"></li>
 </ul>
<button class="add_new" add-contracts>Add New Item</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var app = angular.module('AjApp', []);

 app.controller('ContractsController', function ( $scope ) {
    $scope.count = {
    indx = 1;
}
 });

 app.directive('addContracts', function ( $templateRequest, $templateCache, $compile ) {       
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, ele, attr) {

            ele.on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $contracts = jQuery("ul#contracts");
                scope.count.indx +=1;

               $templateRequest("add_contracts.html" ).then(function(html){
                  var template = angular.element(html);
                  $contracts.append(template);
                  $compile(template)(scope);
               });


            });
        },
    };
});
```

Comment: Not working, same result. all of the id's of li updating to new id

Comment: well what is happening everytime u click on addContacts scope value gets incremented and that get reflected in all the templates

Comment: instead of doing like it you can make an array, and do ng-repeat from ng-repeat which you will get $index .Every time you click on add push in that array

Comment: can you please show me a working example on fiddle or js etc. ?

Comment: will take time ,will do it

Comment: check this no need of directive just add to scope varialble and use ng-include https://plnkr.co/edit/uW2VJt?p=preview